# Remove lines duplicated more than n times

Tags: unix

I want to remove lines duplicated more than 3 times (or 4 times) in the first 3 columns. The main goal is to remove lines where the genomic coordinates are duplicated more than 3 or 4 times.

Input file.tsv

| chr | position | position2 | ref | alt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr21 | 10464942 | 10464942 | T | C |
| chr21 | 10464942 | 10464942 | T | C |
| chr21 | 10464961 | 10464961 | A | G |
| chr21 | 10464961 | 10464961 | C | G |
| chr21 | 10464961 | 10464961 | A | G |
| chr21 | 10464961 | 10464961 | T | C |
| chr21 | 10465086 | 10465086 | T | C |

Desired output if n=3

| chr | position | position2 | ref | alt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr21 | 10464942 | 10464942 | T | C |
| chr21 | 10464942 | 10464942 | T | C |
| chr21 | 10465086 | 10465086 | T | C |

I tried awk '{if(!seen[$1,$2,$3]++) {if(++count[$1,$2,$3]<=3) print} }' and some sort and uniq combinations, but they don't get me the output I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotating with a dup count lets us easily solve this.

Python will be more convenient than awk.

```
import csv
import typer

def get_annotated_rows(sheet, prefix_length=3):
    """Generates (count, row) tuples.

    Count for a row will be 1 if this is the first time we've seen it,
    and increments with each duplicate row.
    We assess duplicates by examining just an initial prefix of each row.
    """
    prev = None
    count = 0
    for row in sheet:
        prefix = row[:prefix_length]
        if prefix != prev:
            prev = prefix
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
        yield count, row

def main(infile: str = "input_file.tsv", n: int = 4):
    with open(infile) as fin:
        sheet = csv.reader(fin, delimiter="\t")
        for count, row in get_annotated_rows(sheet):
            if count <= n:
                print("\t".join(row))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    typer.run(main)
```

[install](https://pypi.org/project/typer):

```
$ pip install typer
```

Answer (score 0):

A common shell scripting trick is to reformat data so it can be processed easily by using *nix utilities. Often the troublesome utility is the `uniq` command, with it `-f` (skip **f**ields option), where fields are skipped at the front of the record. Many times you wish you could skip at the end of the record, so we rely on awk to reformat data to have the skipable fields at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR>1{print $4 " " $5 " " $1 "_" $2 "_" $3 }' data.txt \
| sort -k3 | uniq -cf2 \
| awk '$1<3{
  split($4,arr,"_")
  for (i=1;i<=$1;i++) {
    print arr[1]"\t" arr[2]"\t" arr[3]"\t" $2 " " $3
  }
}'
```

Output

```
chr21   10464942        10464942        T C
chr21   10464942        10464942        T C
chr21   10465086        10465086        T C
```

You can change the field separators in the print statement as needed to match the needs of your consuming system.

(And this code can be folded up onto one line, giving the much desired (if misvalued) "oneliner" (-: ).
IHTH